# Android Studio Emulator and "Process finished with exit code -1073741511 (0xC0000139)"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm trying to emulate my application using Android Studio Emulator (i'm developing by Android Studio) but I receive this error message:

> Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741511 (0xC0000139)

Do what can I do?

Problem image:

[image]

Comment: Please add the stack strace from android studio's monitor.

Comment: That one line is not enough to understand the problem.Please post the whole Logcat result. So someone can help  you.

Comment: @Otavio Migual could you solve this issue in the meantime?

Comment: I believe this error is rooted in Python. Exit code -1073741511 means there is a missing dll. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530001/process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741511-0xc0000139 - this means some aspect of the installation must have gone bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply follow the below points

- Open Android Virtual Device Manager
- Click on Options for Virtual device
- Step 1: Wipe Data
- Step 2: Cold Boot Now
  [image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Android Studio Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1. Maybe disk drive is FULL. You can delete some virtual devices unused. It works for me.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: I have left 4 emolators. But it still triggers : Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)  after a while :/

Comment: What is your simulator configuration?

Comment: @Tuan Nguyen  thank you, openGL renderer -default,  OpenGL API level also was  exposed as autodetect. All dosk space and RAM are auto or default.x86_64 . Windows 10 for 64 type comp.

Comment: I have 1.5 TB disk space, this wasn't the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the above answers and none worked.

I found the root of this issue was because I had removed Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable(x64).

Just install it from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) and restart your computer. It will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

try increasing the ram size of your emulator.

Comment: @OtavioMiguel, can you please share how did you resolve this big problem???

Comment: this was my decision though:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497518/android-studio-3-0-1-shows-process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741819-0xc00000

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

Make sure to select **x86 Images** when creating a new emulator. 
Sometimes the system image under **Reccomended** tab MAY NOT WORK.

[image]

Comment: Didn't help. Again that: Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

increase the ram of the AVD virtual emulator you made and also update the API