# Android Studio Emulator and "Process finished with exit code 0"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I've updated android studio from 3.0 to 3.0.1 but when I launch Emulator it didn't get launched and gives message in event log:

```
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44999569/android-studio-emulator-process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741511-0xc0000139

Comment: Please check the answer before go for the long solutions.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52071261/5022618

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I restarted Android Studio and create a new device in AVD MANAGER then I have increased the RAM size of emulator and it works nicely.

**UPDATED**
Sometimes it happens when you close emulator during building the App in to emulator.

Comment: Increasing the ram size and changing the emulator type from Nexus 5 (the original one) to Nexus 4 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 19):

You need to check:

- Your *size on disk* is not full - this's often happen due to creation of some virtual devices that are unused
- The RAM size of emulator is not minimum as your requirements

One more thing that I personally use: [Use Pen Drive as a RAM](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-Pen-Drive-As-RAM)

---

### Updated:

[Use HDD as RAM](http://tricksnow.com/how-to-use-hard-disk-as-ram-on-windows/)

> - Right Click on “This PC or My Computer” and Select Properties.
> - Now Click on “Advance System Settings”.
> - Now in “System Properties” you have to select “Advanced” tab.
> - Now click on “Settings” Under “Performance”.
> - Now in “Performance Option” again you have to select “Advanced” tab.
> - Now click on “change“ under “Virtual Memory”.
> - Un-check “Automatically manage paging file size of all drivers” and select “Custom size”.
> - In Custom Size enter the amount of data According to “Space available” which is written there.
> - Click on “set” button and Click on OK.
> - Now it will ask you to restart your Computer or Laptop.

---

Another work around steps (tested) :

1. Restart your Android Studio
2. Create new device in your AVD Manager
3. Increase the RAM size of the Emulator

Comment: will that act as an additional RAM?

Comment: Yes, I use these to speed up my AndroidStudio Emulator .

Comment: then you should set the Limit to 7GB or 7.5GB .

Comment: Can i use any drive in my computer other than pen drive if i have an 20gb empty drive?

Comment: didnt work for me. I exposed the limit as suggested 7.5 g.

Comment: @CodeToLife try to setting quota as like [here](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/simple-questions-what-are-disk-quotas-how-set-them-windows) and see?

Comment: @AsifAli72090 , thank you for the advice. No ,I tryd that today,  the emulator now plays  much longer but then again it drops  :
 Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)  :/

Comment: "Increase the RAM size of the Emulator" helped me. thanks.

Answer (score 13):

I also faced the same error. After a few hours I figured it out.

I hope it helps you :

Go to **Tools** ==> **SDK Menager** ==>**Android SDK**

(Appearange&Behavior=>System settings=>Android SDK)==>**SDK Tools**==>**Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator**(install this).

It will solve your problem.I hope it helps.

[image: You can look at pictures which you must install]

Comment: I still have the issue, even after trying the proposed solution above.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem and it took me nearly 2 days to resolve...

I had moved my SDK location, due to the system drive being full, and it seems that someone, somewhere at Android Studio central has hard-coded the path to the HaxM driver installer. As my HamX driver was out of date, the emulator wouldn't start.

Solution: navigate to [your sdk location]\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager and run the intelhaxm-android.exe installer to update yourself to the latest driver.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue in Android Studio 3.1 :

I only have on board graphics. Went to Tools -> AVD Manager -> (Edit this AVD) under Actions -> Emulated Performance (Graphics): select "Software GLES 2.0".

Answer (score 4):

In AVD Manager,

Go to Edit Icon on AVD Manager for selected Device.

Click on show advanced settings and increase ram size from 1500 mb to 2 GB.

Then it works.

NOTE: Some virtual devices do not allow you to update RAM, but if so, try installing Nexus 4. because it does.

NOTE2: If still doesnt work, dont give up. just uninstall and reinstall the device with changing RAM again. in some cases this is how it works

NOTE3: If still doesnt work, this means your pc doesnt have enough ram space. so increase the ram to 3gb. it might work but it will suffer

NOTE4: If still doesnt work, try it with multicore 2 instead of 4.

NOTE5: Still doesnt work. Close the Android Studio and NEVER open it back :)

Comment: ended up with 5th note 

Comment: @devgun :) but dont give up, there should be a solution in somewhere

Comment: Increase of emulator RAM solved the same issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

Docker installation selected Hyper-V on windows by default. Deselect the Hyper-v b

This worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get past this by making sure all my SDKs were up to date. (Mac OS 10.13.3, Android Studio 3.0.1). I went to Android Studio -> Check for Updates... and let it run. Once my Android 5.0/5.1 (API level 21/22) SDKs were updated to revision 2:
[image: Preferences screen showing updated Android 5.0 and 5.1 SDKs]

After doing this update, I was able to run the emulator without crashing out immediately with a "Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0" error.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions worked for me. I upgraded my previous Android Studio to 3.0.1 and received this issue while trying to restart the emulator.

What worked for me was deleting Android Studio from Windows 'Add or Remove Programs'. Then go to C:\Users[User] and delete any android-related folders (.android, .AndroidStudioX.X, Android).

Next go to C:\Users[User]\AppData\Local and delete any Android-related folders there. Restart your system and re-download android studio from their official site (https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html). Install Android Studio from fresh and don't import any old settings.

When Android Studio finishes installing, I launched AVD from 'Tools > Android > AVD Manager', created a pixel 2 device with 4096mb of RAM running Android API P x86. Start it up and it works!

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by the following step:

Please ensure "Windows Hypervisor Platform" is installed. If it's not installed, install it, restart your computer and you will be good to go.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1. Maybe disk drive is FULL. You can delete some virtual devices unused. It works for me.
it's next to the edit in your virtual manager devices menu (the arrow down)

Comment: It may be DISK FULL related in some cases but not for everyone because I am seeing this same issue when I have 32GB RAM (allocated 12GB for HAXM) and 350GB available ROM and still get this and crashes my simulator to load and exits with different error codes!  WEIRD!

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem.I fix this problem by editing Graphics of AVD.
Tools > Androids > AVD Manager >  Actions > Edit > Show Advance Settings > Graphics -> Software.
I hope this solution help u!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete the emulator and reinstall it this usually does the trick for me. Sometimes you also run into hiccups on your computer so try restarting your computer. Your computer may not be able to handle android studio if so there is nothing you can do. Consequently, you may not have the right ram requirements. Finally, If all else fails you can try to delete then reinstall android studio.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by offing all of advantage features of my graphics card in its settings(Nvidaa type). It started to throw such hanging error less a lot. But finally I found a simplier way: In avd manager you need to put less resolution for the avd. Say, 400x800. Then I reenabled graphics card features again and now it runs all ok. (I suspect my graphics card or cpu are weaker than needed. )

Answer (score 0):

**In my case, *Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0* error started after I pressed on Restart in the Emulator.**

It happened because in Android Studio 3.0 and up versions, the emulator saves the states of the current screen to launch it very quickly at next time. So when I pressed on Restart it closes emulator by saving state as Restart. So when I launch/start the emulator, it executes the Save States as Restart and then after emulator is not started automatically. So basically it stuck in to Save States of Restart.

I don't want to delete existing emulator and create a new one.
My default Boot Option of Emulator was Quick boot in AVD.
**By doing Cold Boot Now from AVD (Android Virtual Device) Manager, it starts emulator again in normal mode without Save State.**

[image]

**Cold boot start emulator as from power up.**

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the following error when starting the emulator and none of the answers fixed it.

Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)

Finally I found that Visual C++ is not installed in my system. If it is not installed please install Visual C++ and check.

Please find the link below to download latest Visual C++.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: you exit code is different from the code mentioned in question