# Emulator: Process finished with exit code 2

Tags: android, android-emulator

```
07/12 12:33:43: Launching app
Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Nexus_6_API_24 was killed.
```

How can it be resolved? I am not being able to use emulator because of this error.

Comment: Now can you answer it? @PankajKumar

Comment: Sure. Similar answer I found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739661/android-studio-emulator-and-process-finished-with-exit-code-0

Comment: @PankajKumar And what does this mean ? Emulator: Could not launch 'C:\Users\Anushka Sharma\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe': No such file or directory

Comment: I think some of images you did not downloaded for that particular API version.. Check once