# Emulator: Unable to launch on macbook

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am new to Android Studio and I am setting up an Emulator. 
I use a Macbook Pro and when I try to run my emulator (Pixel 2 API 28) I get the below errors and the emulator does not run.

13:43   Emulator: dyld: Symbol not found: _kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom

13:43   Emulator: Referenced from: /Users/eimearbrady/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5WebEngineCoreAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)

13:43   Emulator: Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

13:43   Emulator: in /Users/eimearbrady/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5WebEngineCoreAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib

13:43   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 133 (interrupted by signal 5: SIGTRAP)

Comment: Try by setting `Emulated Performance Graphics` option to **Software**

Comment: Also check this one, there may be memory issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47871508/2637449

Comment: Thanks the issue is solved I changed the Emulated Performance Graphics option to Software as you said and updated my Mac to the latest OS X version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by setting `Emulated Performance Graphics` option to `Software`

Comment: Hello Md.Asaduzzaman,

After chage Emulated Performance Graphics to software still facing same error