# emulator trying to erase a non-existent color buffer with handle 0 android studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am just new to android studio and I tried to emulate app for the first time. When I click on Image button and the emulator goes back to main activity with an error "emulator trying to erase a non-existent color buffer with handle 0".

Please tell me the steps solve to this problem

Comment: Maybe this might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739661/android-studio-emulator-and-process-finished-with-exit-code-0

Comment: Hi sanil thanks for the help but i got my issue resolved for now

Comment: @RAY Could you please post your solution?