# Android Studio logcat printing lot of errors

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am currently working on an android project. But now when I open the emulator it shows too many errors in logcat and those are looping on it. But the emulator worked fine yesterday. Today I just `wipe data` in the emulator and those errors start to showing in logcat after that. I delete the emulator and recreate it but those errors are still coming. Do you guys have any idea why those errors come and how to fix those?

Few images of errors that looping on logcat

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqO4E.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuIzU.png)

[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q45s4.png)

[image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJb7w.png)

The emulator that I am using

[image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoViZ.png)

Comment: They are not fatal errors and you have no problem for using AVD

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739661/android-studio-emulator-and-process-finished-with-exit-code-0

Comment: But is there any way to fix those? @MMG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some errors in AS are fatal, it means that your app or AVD can't run with them. But some of them are not important issues, you can run your app or AVD even there are red lines in logcat.

Comment: Yeah, My application working fine but is there any way to stop those?

Comment: They are in error part of logcat but they are not errors that can make issue for your app. We may solve some of them but it seems that all of them are not solvable with us. @Goodman