# My Logcat full of input svInfo.flags is 8

Tags: android, kotlin, butterknife

I converted Java file to Kotlin file.
It happen when I click button from Dashboard and keep stopped working.

My logcat is full of input svInfo.flags is 8.

How to solve it? I've already closed GPS and added this activity to AndroidManifest.

From logcat,there are problem in setupStepView() but I don't what problem is?

```
class BookingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @BindView(R.id.step_view)
    var stepView: StepView? = null

    @BindView(R.id.view_pager)
    var viewPager: ViewPager? = null

    @BindView(R.id.btn_next_step)
    var btn_next_step: Button? = null

    @BindView(R.id.btn_previous_step)
    var btn_previous_step: Button? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_booking)
        ButterKnife.bind(this@BookingActivity)
        setupStepView()
        setColorButton()

        //View
        viewPager!!.adapter = MyViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        viewPager!!.addOnPageChangeListener(object : OnPageChangeListener {
            override fun onPageScrolled(
                position: Int,
                positionOffset: Float,
                positionOffsetPixels: Int)
            {
            }

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    btn_previous_step!!.isEnabled = false }
                    else {
                    btn_previous_step!!.isEnabled = true
                    setColorButton()
                }
            }

            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {

            }
        }
        )
    }

    private fun setupStepView() {
        val stepList: MutableList<String> =
            ArrayList()
        stepList.add("Clinic")
        stepList.add("Doctor")
        stepList.add("Time")
        stepList.add("Confirmation")
        stepView!!.setSteps(stepList)
    }

    private fun setColorButton() {
        if (btn_next_step!!.isEnabled) {
            btn_next_step!!.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary)
        } else {
            btn_next_step!!.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
        }
        if (btn_previous_step!!.isEnabled) {
            btn_previous_step!!.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary)
        } else {
            btn_previous_step!!.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary)
        }
    }
```

This's from my logcat.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)
        at butterknife.Unbinder.<clinit>(Unbinder.java:9)
        at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:165)
        at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:99)
        at npa.sit.cpoint.BookingActivity.onCreate(BookingActivity.kt:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61821009/12478830

Comment: But mine don't work fine. Cryyy

Comment: Check logcat to see what is the error

Comment: I found that there's error in line with ButterKnife.bind(this@BookingActivity) but I don't know what error is

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You can see on my post now,sir.

Comment: It looks like the ButterKnife library might be expecting a java class. You might be able to get past the error by changing from `ButterKnife.bind(this@BookingActivity)` to  `ButterKnife.bind(this@BookingActivity::class.java)`.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453010/android-kotlin-with-butterknife