# Android Studio V4.0.1 AVD Phone Emulator Refuses to Open

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I've created a new project based on the "Google Maps Activity" template, and I'm trying to test the app to see how it functions. The only thing the program does is make a map marker in Sydney, Australia and position the camera there. I created a Google Pixel emulator using AVD Manager, but it refuses to open every single time I try to launch the app OR the emulator. I'm brand new to Android Studio, so I have no idea how to debug this. I even created an account on this site so I can get help. Anyone know what could be causing this?

Here's the error code that appears in the Event Log:
`7:55 PM  Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

The specs for the Google Pixel emulator are below:

```
Name: Pixel API 30
OS:  Android 10.0+ x86
Graphics: Automatic
Boot option: Cold Boot
RAM: 1536 MB
VM Heap: 228 MB
Internal Storage: 3 GB
SD Card: studio-managed 512 MB
```

Comment: Try looking at this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739661/android-studio-emulator-and-process-finished-with-exit-code-0/47871508