# In android studio I cant get my emulator to run

Tags: android-studio, emulation

Continously I am getting the same error when I try to run my emulator.

3:20 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: Check this answer, it will reslove your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47871508/7089760

Comment: U are welcome 