# Android studio 3.0.1 shows Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to use an marshmallow api 23 emulator on Android studio 3.0.1 on Win 7 64bit and getting this error:

> 7:03 PM  Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2
>   CPU0 thread'. No response for 15000 ms
>
> 7:03 PM   Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819
>   (0xC0000005)

In general ever since I have updated to 3.0.1 from 3.0 I have been getting endless AVD errors. If it helps, this error came right after I unticked the pcstore.bin from "Read-only".

Comment: So are you getting this when you attempt to run with an emulator (I'm assuming so).  If so have you deleted and re-added the emulator.  Do you have the ability to run it directly to a real device and if so do you get any errors from it?

Comment: I can run the app on a real device. The problem is the emulator. Do you suggest deleting and rebuilding the emulator? Because this is a problem I have with all of my AVD's, new and old.

Comment: "Because this is a problem I have with all of my AVD's, new and old. " so you are using an AVD from previous Android Studio and it is not offered in the current version?

Comment: @justdan0227 Nah AVD persist through version changes and updates if thats what you ask

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by offing all of advantage features of my  graphics card in its settings(Nvidia type). It started to throw such hanging error less a lot. But finally I found a simplier way:
In avd manager you need to put less resolution for the avd. Say, 400x800.
Then I reenabled graphics card features again and now it runs all ok.
(I suspect my graphics card or  cpu are weaker than needed. )