# Emulator: emulator: ERROR: can't find the emulator executable.Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

[LogCat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EK21.png) [Error:Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azrs3.png)  I was working on android studio, and my AVD stopped responding so I closed it forcefully through task manager. But then everytime I run the AVD it give a message that its already running or opened in a file or folder.Then, I installed another AVD. But then,I figured out which file is opened. I found some qemu-system file which was not being closed through task manager as well. So, I went to file location and deleted that file but after that I am not able to launch the emulator. It's giving an error message:

Emulator: emulator: ERROR: can't find the emulator executable.
Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1

What should I do? Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47631771/emulator-process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741819-0xc0000005)

Comment: No, I am still getting the same error. Please solve my problem.

Comment: u can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52071261/10967323) follow step bye step .

Comment: Not working. I am getting exit code -1

Comment: what actually issue please explain in detail show log.

Comment: I have posted the photo of log, there's nothing in log, my emulator is not launching. As, i click the run button, it gives that error message in the event log